# Algorithm for combinations

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, combinations, permutation

This is the Programm:

```
    public List<List<Fieldmatrix>> permute(List<Fieldmatrix> fields, int start, List<Fieldmatrix> prefix) {

    List<List<Fieldmatrix>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

        if (start >= fields.size()) {
            combinations.add(prefix);
            return combinations;
        }
        String field = fields.get(start).getFieldName();
        if (fields.get(start).isMandatory() == false) {
            combinations.addAll(combine(fields, start + 1, prefix));
        }
        List<Fieldmatrix> prefixWithField = new ArrayList<>(prefix);
        prefixWithField.add(new Fieldmatrix (field, fields.get(start).isMandatory(), fields.get(start).getFieldtype(), new ArrayList<>()));
        combinations.addAll(combine(fields, start + 1, prefixWithField));

        return combinations;
    }
```

My Idea was: For example I have an XML with these fields

- Field1, true
- Field2, true
- Field3, false
- Field4, false
- Field5, false

The results are:

- {Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5}
- {Field1, Field2,       ,    Field4, Field5}
- {Field1, Field2,       ,       , Field5}
- {Field1,    Field2,       ,       ,       }
- {Field1, Field2, Field3,       ,    Field5}
- {Field1, Field2, Field3,       ,       }
- {Field1, Field2,    Field3, Field4,       }
- {Field1, Field2,       , Field4,       }

The fields have the value true or false. False fields can be deleted. So the program finds every possible combination of these fields.

Fieldmatrix:

```
public class Fieldmatrix {

private String fieldName;
private boolean mandatory;
private Type fieldtype;
private List<Fieldmatrix> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Fieldmatrix(String fieldName, boolean mandatory, Type fieldtype, List<Fieldmatrix> list){
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.mandatory = mandatory;
    this.fieldtype = fieldtype;
    this.list = list;
}
//Getters and Setters
```

This program works only for "1-dimensional" Lists, this means if any field has no fields in his own list.

I want to update this code.
Now I have a structure like this:

- Field 1, true
- Field 2, true
- Field 3, false

  - Subfield 1, true
  - Subfield 2, true

    - Subsubfield 1, false

Subfield 1 and Subfield 2 are in the list of Field 3. Subsubfield 1 is in Subfield 2.

How should I Change the code, so that works for more dimensional examples?

Has anybody an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order doesn't matter, you can use a way to generate all combinations of optional (i.e. FALSE params in your case) as follows:

Let's say you have 3 optional params, and 2 compulsory params.
So you will have 3^2 = 9 combinations.

Now, all you have to do is iterate 9 times to generate all possible combinations.

Just a pseudo code:

Your options: ["A", "B", "C"]
3^2=9 possibilities.

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
  for(j=0;j<options.length;j++){
    if(j'th bit is set in 'i')
      print(options[j]);
  }
}
```

You can google to check if a particular bit is set or not.

Hope this is enough to get you started.
All the best.

Comment: The order matters. The problem is I have to update the algorithm so that it works with the list of each field.

Comment: My bad, this algorithm will give you the same output as required. Just that you'll have to do some juggling around the code to accommodate TRUE values. You should give it a try.

Comment: But with the algorothm I already accomodate true values, the Problem is I cannot handle f.e. Fields3.list and Subfield2.list.

Comment: No one an idea?